# TTK Notebook Share data between imported tabs

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I designed an application using the ttk notebook and I created three tab. Everyone of them has a starkly distinct and complex layout and very few functions and methods in common between them.

As a result, the code file is getting quite hard to understand with so many line of code dedicated to the layout.

There is a way to create every tab as a separate module/file/class and "import" them, so that they can be easier to maintain?

EDIT:

The problem I had was how to share attributes between the Frame subclass to the main application.
The solution was simply add a second argument to the Frame subclass.
To be more specific, I wanted to use the "common_text" and "font" attributes from the main.py in the two notebooks.
It now works, even thou I don't know if this is the correct solution.

main.py

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import first_tab
import second_tab

class Application(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super(Application, self).__init__()
        self.common_text = "This is a test"
        self.font = ('courier', 10, 'bold')

        self.root = root
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
        self.notebook.pack(fill='both', expand = 'yes')
        self.tab_1 = first_tab.tab_frame(self)
        self.tab_2 = second_tab.tab_frame(self)
        self.notebook.add(self.tab_1, text = "First Tab")
        self.notebook.add(self.tab_2, text = "Second Tab")

root = Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.title("Utility")
root.mainloop()
```

first_tab.py

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class tab_frame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, relative):
        Frame.__init__(self)

        self.F_1_00 = Frame(self)
        self.F_1_00.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.F_1_10 = Frame(self)
        self.F_1_10.grid(column=0, row=1)

        self.sign = Label(self.F_1_00, text = relative.common_text, pady=10)
        self.sign.configure(font = relative.font)
        self.sign.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.reset = Button(self.F_1_10, text = "First", width = 10)
        self.reset.grid(column=2, row=3, padx = 10)
```

second_tab.py

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class tab_frame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, relative):
        Frame.__init__(self)

        self.F_2_00 = Frame(self)
        self.F_2_00.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.F_2_10 = Frame(self)
        self.F_2_10.grid(column=0, row=1)

        self.sign = Label(self.F_2_00, text = relative.common_text, pady=10)
        self.sign.configure(font = relative.font)
        self.sign.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.reset = Button(self.F_2_10, text = "Second", width = 10)
        self.reset.grid(column=2, row=3, padx = 10)
```

Comment: Of course it's possible. Every tab contains a frame, every frame is is an object. Classes can be put in files, and objects can be created in separate files. It's all just python code, and python code can be split into as many files as you want. Try it, and then come back here when you have a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't, however, understand the downvote. I lost count of how many books and websites I looked before post my answer. And before posting, I made sure no one had made the same question or indirectly answered with an example.
I know your answer: I didn't post any code. Maybe because I didn't know where to start?

Comment: We all get downvotes that are hard to explain. In this case it's likely because your question shows a complete lack of any research on your part, and doesn't include any code to show that you've tried anything. If you did research, show it as part of your question. Though, don't just say "I read a bunch of books". You need to try some things on your own. You should also add more detail - - have you ever written _any_ python code that was spread across multiple files? You're asking about one of the most fundamental parts of writing python code.

Comment: I acknowledge that the question was poorly written.

Comment: Should / could cancel the question?

Comment: SO, is your real question about the sharing of data? Based on your edit it looks like you know how to split the code into files. If the real question is about sharing data, please edit the question and change the title to reflect what you're actually asking about.

Comment: Yes, I understand my question was way too generic. 
I just started write GUIs and i don't know what is the best way to import pieces of GUI in order to make a larger application that can work reusing a common part of code (and datas).
For instance, is subclassing the Frame class and add a second argument correct? can that expose the code to errors and "awkwardness" (that I'm not able to forsee?).
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting notebook tabs in separate files is no different than putting any other python code in separate files.

For example, create a file named "page1.py" with the following contents:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1")
        label.pack(fill ="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)
```

Create a second file with nearly identical contents, changing "1" to "2":

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2")
        label.pack(fill ="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)
```

Now, create a main application that uses these two files:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
from page1 import Page1
from page2 import Page2

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        page1 = Page1(self.notebook)
        page2 = Page2(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(page1, text="Page 1")
        self.notebook.add(page2, text="Page 2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

If you need to share data between these two classes, they must share something. For example, you could have a common dictionary that gets passed in to each frame. For example:

```
self.app_data = {...}
page1 = Page1(self.notebook, self.app_data)
page2 = Page2(self.notebook, self.app_data)
```

Another solution is to adopt a bit of the model-view-controller pattern, where the app is the controller.

```
page1 = Page1(self.notebook. self)
...
class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller)
        self.controller = controller
    ...
    def some_function(self):
        # get data from page 2
        page = self.controller.get_page("Page2")
        data = page.data
```

Tkinter is no different than any other python code in this regard. If two objects -- no matter what the class -- need access to the same information, they must be given the information or be given a way to access the information.

Comment: I had problem sharing attributes between the main class and the Frame subclass that I istantiated from the imported module.
I solved by adding a second argument in the Frame subclass.
I will add a snipet of code in my main answer, even thou I agree that I should have done it beefore.

Thanks again.