# Running Function and adding New Frame Tkinter/Python

Tags: python, button, methods, tkinter

I have a MainPage class in Tkinter.  This class consists of OptionMenus, Entrys and One Button.  The idea is that people select values from the OptionMenu's, enter in ints into the Entry widgets and then press the button to process their query. When they click the button it will run the function that processes their query and show the result in a new frame.

Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)

def combine_funcs(*funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
    return combined_func


class database(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        ###Sets the Window title
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self,"Database Searcher")
        ###Container is our Frame
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        ###Sets where this is
        container.pack(side="top", fill ="both", expand = True)
        ###Setting Row Attributes
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight =1)
        #Makes a Dictionary for adding more Frames
        self.frames = {}
        ###Main Page Frame
        for F in (MainPage,ResultPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
        ###Added Main Page as our Frame
            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "nsew")
        ###Shows the main frame
        self.show_frame(MainPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        global option_String_Var
        global data_String_Var
        global entry_String_Var
        global year_String_Var
        global mon_String_Var
        global site_String_Var
        ####Init the Frame
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        ###Label the Page as Main Page
        label = tk.Label(self, text ="Fill out the Information Below", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack()
        ###Create a Month Dropdown Menu
        monList = ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12')
        mon_String_Var = tk.StringVar()
        monMenu = ttk.OptionMenu(self,mon_String_Var, 'Month', *monList)
        monMenu.pack(side="top")
        ####Make an Entry for Year Data
        year_String_Var = tk.StringVar(self, value = 'Enter Year')
        yearEntry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable = year_String_Var)
        yearEntry.pack()

        ###Sites
        siteList  = ('KMCI','KMKC','KCOU','KSTJ','KJEF','KSGF','KSTL')
        site_String_Var = tk.StringVar()
        siteOptionMenu = ttk.OptionMenu(self, site_String_Var,'Site',*siteList)
        siteOptionMenu.pack()

        ###Our dataList tuple for the dataList Option Menu
        dataList = ('High Temp','Low Temp','Precipitation','Snowfall', 'Snow Depth')
        ###Need to make a SringVar for the Menu ( this is how the .get() method works
        data_String_Var = tk.StringVar()
        optionMenu2 = ttk.OptionMenu(self,data_String_Var,dataList[0],*dataList)
        ###Pack it and add it!
        optionMenu2.pack(side ='left')
        #####Operator Option Menu
        operatorList = ('Equal To','Greater Than','Less Than','Greater Than or Equal To',
                      'Less Than or Equal To')
        option_String_Var = tk.StringVar()
        optionMenu1 = ttk.OptionMenu(self,option_String_Var,operatorList[0],*operatorList)
        optionMenu1.pack(side ='left')

        ###Make a Entry text box for inputting the Values
        entry_String_Var = tk.StringVar(self, value = 'Enter Value Here')
        entry1 = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable = entry_String_Var)
        entry1.pack(side ="left", padx = 5)
        ###Add a Buttom commanded to databaseCalc Formula that makes
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = 'Get Data!', command = combine_funcs(self.databaseCalc,lambda: controller.show_frame(ResultPage)))
        button1.pack()

    def databaseCalc(self):
        data_selection = data_String_Var.get()
        operator = option_String_Var.get()
        data_value = int(entry_String_Var.get())
        year_value = int(year_String_Var.get())
        site_value = site_String_Var.get()
        mon_value = int(mon_String_Var.get())

        df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/Daily Data Proc/' + site_value +'.csv')

        data = (df[data_selection]).as_matrix()
        month =  (df['MONTH']).as_matrix()
        year = (df['YEAR']).as_matrix()

        if operator == 'Equal To':
            indc = np.where((data == data_value) & (month == mon_value) & (year == year_value))
            temp = data[indc]
            amount = (np.ones_like(temp)).sum()
        elif operator == 'Greater Than':
            indc = np.where((data > data_value) & (month == mon_value) & (year == year_value))
            temp = data[indc]
            amount = (np.ones_like(temp)).sum()        
        elif operator == 'Less Than':
            indc = np.where((data < data_value) & (month == mon_value) & (year == year_value))
            temp = data[indc]
            amount = (np.ones_like(temp)).sum()
        elif operator == 'Greater Than or Equal To':
            indc = np.where((data >= data_value) & (month == mon_value) & (year == year_value))
            temp = data[indc]
            amount = (np.ones_like(temp)).sum()
        elif operator == 'Less than or Equal To':
            indc = np.where((data <= data_value) & (month == mon_value) & (year == year_value))
            temp = data[indc]
            amount = (np.ones_like(temp)).sum()
        print str(amount)

class ResultPage(tk.Frame,MainPage):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        ###Create a Label with the results that we would like to displa


        ###Create a Button to go Backwards
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text = 'Run Another Query', command = lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage))
        button2.pack()



app =  database()
app.mainloop()
```

So my main issue, I believe, is first of all I have global variables and I don't want that.  The second issue is that I have my databaseCalc() function outside of the class. I know many people say to have that as a method inside of my class for main page.  I have gotten that to work, but then when I want to display my amount variable as the result in Class ResultPage, it throws an error.  My OOP is, admittedly, terrible.  Can anyone help me out with how to get this to work?

I'm struggling with how to pass variables from one class into another class so that I can display the variable on the ResultPage.

Thanks!!

Edit:  What I want to do, is something like this in the ResultPage class.

```
class ResultPage(tk.Frame,MainPage):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        ###Create a Label with the results that we would like to displa
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text = str(amount))
        label1.pack()

        ###Create a Button to go Backwards
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text = 'Run Another Query', command = lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage))
        button2.pack()
```

The issue I am running into is when I call the variable amount from class MainPage I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\tkintertest.py", line 183, in <module>
    app =  database()
  File "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\tkintertest.py", line 33, in __init__
    frame = F(container, self)
  File "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\tkintertest.py", line 175, in __init__
    label = tk.Label(self, text = str(amount))
NameError: global name 'amount' is not defined
```

How to I pass the variable amount from the MainPage class into ResultPage class.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check the indentation of your code. Repaste your code into the textarea, then select all of the code and press `ctrl+k` on keyboard or click the `{}` button on the toolbar.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala  I have made the changes as well as adding my calculation function inside of the MainPage Class.

Comment: Instead of `global`s, store them as attributes to `self`; `self.mon_field = StringVar(...)` and so on.

Comment: Also note that the error in your traceback does not match your code.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala  Fixed the traceback.  So when I make my variables attributes of self in the __init__ method of MainPage, how do I call them into class Result Page?

Comment: See this answer for information about sharing data between classes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36039264/7432