# Tkinter Share data between (Notebook) Tabs

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs, share

I have found a very interesting post under the title "TTK Notebook Share Data Between Imported Tabs".

Here is the link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032712/ttk-notebook-share-data-between-imported-tabs][1]

This is the main application:

I've created as described there and it works.
But how can I share data between these two classes?

For example, if I write the following code to the Main Application:

```
self.hello = "Hello World"
page1 = Page1(self.notebook, self.hello)
page2 = Page2(self.notebook, self.hello)
```

I get the error message:

page1 = Page1(self.notebook, self.app_data)

TypeError: **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I have been working on it for days, but unfortunately I do not understand where the mistake is.
I would be very happy if someone would help me here.

This is the main application (main.py):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from page1 import Page1
from page2 import Page2

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        page1 = Page1(self.notebook)
        page2 = Page2(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(page1, text="Tab 1")
        self.notebook.add(page2, text="Tab 2")

        self.hello = "Hello World"
        page1 = Page1(self.notebook, self.hello)
        page2 = Page2(self.notebook, self.hello)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

This is the page1 "page1.py":

```
import tkinter as tk

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Das ist Tab 1"+ self.hello)
        label.pack(fill ="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)
```

And thi is page2 "page2.py":

```
import tkinter as tk

class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Das ist Tab 2"+ self.hello)
        label.pack(fill ="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)
```

Comment: Without seeing a [mcve] we can only guess, and might guess wrong.

Comment: Ok, I have now inserted the complete sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong:

```
page1 = Page1(self.notebook, self.app_data)

TypeError: __init()__ takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

As we can see, your `Page2.__init__` takes two positional arguments: `self` and `parent`. When you do `Page1(self.notebook, self.app_data)`, `self` is automatically passed to `__init__` as the first argument. `self.notebook` is passed as `parent`, and there's no third parameter to accept `self.app_data`.

You need to modify `__init__` to accept the data parameter:

```
class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, app_data):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.app_data = app_data
```

Be aware that will cause a different line to fail, because you also call `Page2` without that extra argument here:

```
page1 = Page1(self.notebook)
```

It's unclear why you're creating `page1` twice, but you need to be consistent in how you're creating it.

Comment: I'm really excited, thank you!
I still have a question for this. Do I need in this code (class Page2(tk.Frame) this line also. self.app_data = app_data       I have found that it works also without this.